# Searching for keywords in the comments of a data frame

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning

I have this dataset which I am checking to confirm if the ID for each animal is correct across years. To do this, I am searching the comments in the Excel file for keywords using this code:

```
    do.call(rbind,breeder[-1]) %>%   
                select(Year, `Old Tag`, Tag_11, PIT, Sex  Orig, Group,Comments) %>% 
filter(Sex != "m",grepl(keywords, Comments)) %>%   
        arrange(., desc(PIT)) %>%   
        print.data.frame
```

Here are the keywords:

```
keywords <- c('retag','lost','Was', 'was','original','change','CHANGE','check','CHECK','switched','temp only','should',
              'had tag','new','give','GIVE', 'given','^--', 'tag', 'TAG', 'tags', 'tagged', 'temp', 'Temporarily', 
              'Temporary', 'Released', 'removed', 'Processing', 'processing', 'Processed', 'previously', 'pit', 'pits', 
              'PIT', 'orig', 'original', 'old', 'OLD', 'new', 'New', 'not', 'listed', 'last', 'had', 
              'could', 'Chech', 'assigned')
```

When I run the code, however, R only uses the first word - 'retag', and I get this output:

```
  Year Old Tag Tag_11              PIT Sex Orig Group                       Comments
1 2015    <NA>    367 <NA>   f c   o Temporary tag -  retag as #3
2 2016    <NA>    367 <NA>   f c   o Temporary tag -  retag as #3
Warning message:
In grepl(keywords, Comments) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I need to search the comments for all the keywords in the data frame, how do you search for multiple words?

Update: When I use the following code, all the arguments are not identified in the output. What am I doing wrong? For instance, 'Released' is not read.

```
 deadKeywords <- c('died', 'Released', 'processed', 'Processed', 'processing', 'Processing', 'process', 'dead', 'Dead', 'Died') %>% paste0(., collapse = " | ")

 commentSearch <- do.call(rbind,breeder[-1]) %>% 
select(Year, Old Tag, Tag_11, PIT, Sex, Orig, Group, Comments) %>% 
filter(grepl(deadKeywords, Comments)) %>% arrange(., desc(PIT)) %>% 
print.data.frame
```

Comment: I've looked at your edited questipn but I fail to see where you created a keyword-pattern with the code I offered. You never provided a full example of what you are calling the "Excel file"

Comment: I figured it out - the problem was the spaces in collapse = " | ". It should have been collapse = "|". Thank you for the help though.

Comment: My answer _never_ had spaces in the `collapse` argument.

Comment: That must have been me by mistake

Comment: You probably were misled by the differences in apparent spacing between the monospaced font used in code blocks and the proportional spacing in the "regular" sections of text used by SO. I agree there is an appearance of spaces around that "pipe" in the code segments, but they're not there if you copy from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grepl` function is not vectorized in its pattern. In order to get the pattern argument to be "vectorized" in the sense of matching any of the items in a character vector, you need to bind them together with the regex "|"-operator so your pattern argument to grepl should be:

```
 paste0( keywords, collapse="|")
```

The other way to use this (possibly useful if keywords is a really long vector):

```
any( sapply( keywords, grepl, x=Comments) )
```

Comment: When I use the updated code, the output differs depending on what word the keywords vector starts with - do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Without an example I don’t think an answer would be possible.

Comment: I realize I edited your answer, apologies. I have updated my question above - any help would be appreciated.